# Encrypting connection strings for a web farm in Release Management

Tags: encryption, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am on Visual Studio/Release Management 2013.4.  Has anyone written a tool for the toolbox to encrypt web.config files for a web farm?  I know you can do it manually with aspnet_regiis.exe but was just wondering if someone had worked out a good process for using it within Microsoft Release Management.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already found a perfect solution. The Release Management toolbox is fully user-extensible. Go ahead and make a custom action that calls `aspnet_regiis.exe` with the appropriate command line parameters and you're all set.

I've done this for customers that need config files to be encrypted, it works wonderfully.

Comment: There is one complication of having the private key imported across the whole web farm for the decryption to work.  Any thoughts on doing that in RM?